# Is there a way to render parent components before subroutes in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a component with a router-outlet defined in it (ParentComponent).

```
<mat-accordion>some content</mat-accordion>
<mat-progress-bar *ngIf="loading"></mat-progress-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I also have a router module with a route definition:

```
{path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent, children: {path: 'sub', loadChildren: () => import('./sub/sub.module').then(mod => mod.SubModule)}}
```

So it lazy loads the SubModule module which has only one path that renders after some data resolved:

```
{path: '', component: SubComponent, resolve: {data: SubResolverService}
```

By default the user is going through the 'parent' route first and only later loads 'parent/sub' using a button so the accordion and the loading is shown.

However, when the url is written explicitly and we go straight to the 'parent/sub' route, the app waits for the sub resolver to get the data and only after this does it render the accordion and progress bar, so the user has to stare at a blank page until every route data is loaded.

Is there a way to render the parent component first, show the progress bar and only after that starting to resolve the sub route?

Comment: Also this is my first question here and I found my problem a bit hard to describe so I'd appreciate any feedback on how to improve my question as well.

Comment: This is an interesting question and something I've run into before. As a work-around I've moved logic out of the resolver and into a master component on the lazy loaded route. I'm curious to see if there are other solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The router wait for the resolver to finish (event child resolver). Resolvers bring data to the component synchronously.
For a better user experience, you should use resolver when the data is available instantly (such as configuration data) otherwise you should use Observable inside the component to avoid blocking the display

Comment: This will be the solution and yes, the Angular guide says that the resolver is delaying the rendering of the routed component but it also says that the use case of this interface is exactly to not show the user a blank screen, just fetch data before it routes to that one component so I guessed it should be logical to render everything else and after that start resolving and blocking. Also most tutorials I read use resolvers to fetch data from an API so those will hang as well when the user wants to access those urls explicitly. Thanks for the answer anyways!